# Delete ListView item from database onClick, using MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-mvp

I'm implementing MVP pattern in my app, and I need to delete an item from the ListView and Database when clicked a delete button, but I don't want to instantiate the DB in the Adapter, or I'll be breaking MVP pattern as I understand.

**Adapter class**

```
public class ProductoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {

    private Context mContext;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private List<Product> listaProductos;

    public ProductoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Product> list) {
        super(context,0,list);
        mContext = context;
        layoutResourceId = resource;
        listaProductos = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null) {
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.producto,parent,false);
            ButterKnife.bind(this,listItem);
        }

        final Product currentProducto = listaProductos.get(position);

        TextView name = listItem.findViewById(R.id.nameTextView);
        name.setText(currentProducto.getName());

        TextView kilos = listItem.findViewById(R.id.kilosTextView);
        kilos.setText(String.valueOf(currentProducto.getKilos()));

        TextView price = listItem.findViewById(R.id.priceTextView);
        price.setText(String.valueOf(currentProducto.getPricePerKilo()));

        ImageButton delete = listItem.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

        return listItem;
    }
}
```

I guess I should use deleteButton.setOnClickListener(), but how I implement this with MVP pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed it out right use `deleteButton.setOnClickListener()` in adapter. Here's a reference to layout this.

> Interface - For Callback from Adapter - Delete Item Action → Activity

```
interface OnItemClickListener {
 void onItemClick(int itemId)
}
```

> Activity - Implements Interface → To handle callback from Adapter - Delete Item Action
>
> Presenter - Handle the event from Activity to your Presenter

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
OnItemClickListener, YourView {

YourPresenter presenter;
YourAdapter adapter;
...

adapter.setListener(this);
....
 @Override
 public void onItemClick(final int itemId) {
// Your callback
 presenter.delete(itemId)
 }
}
```

> Adapter - To register callback which will be sent to Activity

```
 public class ProductoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Product> {
 private final OnItemClickListener listener;

  public setListener(final OnItemClickListener listener) {
   this.listener = listener;
  } 

  @NonNull
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItem = convertView;
    if(listItem == null) {
        listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.producto,parent,false);
        ButterKnife.bind(this,listItem);
    }

    final Product currentProducto = listaProductos.get(position);
    ...
    ImageButton delete = listItem.findViewById(R.id.delete_btn);

     delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
     listener.onItemClick(convertView, position, name);
       }
      });

    return listItem;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using an interface. Below is the implementation

**interface**

```
    public interface ProductoItemClickListener {

        void onDeleteClick(Product product);
    }
```

**In Adapter**

Define listener variable in Adapter class
    private ProductoItemClickListener itemClickListener;

Modify your constructor as below

```
 public ProductoAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, List<Product> list,ProductoItemClickListener itemClickListener ) {
        super(context,0,list);
        mContext = context;
        layoutResourceId = resource;
        listaProductos = list;
        this.itemClickListener = itemClickListener
    }
```

In getView method perform on clicklistener

```
delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
        itemClickListener.onDeleteClick(currentProducto );
});
```

**In activity or Fragment**

```
private ProductoItemClickListener mItemClickListener = new ProductoItemClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDeleteClick(Product product){
       //perform action here
    }
}
```

While initializing adapter pass this mItemClickListener as an last parameter.

This will work!!.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. The accepted answer was more complete though

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve what you are looking for using composition, you can modify your adapter (constructor) to recieve a class that should work as coordinator that implements the Listener. Then add it to your Deletebutton.

That Class should handle the job of deleting or invoke a method on your Adapter.